# Zookeeper can not run becuase of Invalid config

Tags: config, apache-zookeeper

The problem is when I run "./zkServer.sh start" , zookeeper STRATED. But when I check the status, it shows:

```
Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

I create three nodes on vmware, and my config is

```
tickTime=2000 
dataDir=/usr/src/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=192.168.237.129:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.237.130:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.237.132:2888:3888
```

I've already created myid:
[myid and zookeeper creates zookeeper_server.pid each time when I start zookeeper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cumOi.jpg)

Zookeper does not use myid, but creates a new random zookeeper_server.pid each time.

Below is the zookeeper.out:

```
2016-06-09 19:06:28,768 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /usr/src/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2016-06-09 19:06:28,778 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@340] - Defaulting to majority quorums
2016-06-09 19:06:28,779 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerMain@85] - Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing /usr/src/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:123)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:101)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /usr/src/zookeeper/myid file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:119)
    ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: when I run "./zkServer.sh start" , zookeeper STRATED. But when I check the status, it shows: Error contacting service. It is probably not running.

Comment: Myid is created correctly in  /usr/src/zookeeper/. I don't know why zookeeper can not find it.